# How to read FTP login data stored within nautilus?

Tags: 11.04, nautilus, configuration, password, password-recovery

I *forgot* my ftp user name and password, yet I have a bookmark stored within nautilus so I can still access it. I wonder if I could extract these data from nautilus.

Answer (score 5):

On my system (ubuntu 11.10 64bit Unity3D) these passwords are stored in "seahorse".